# How does angular2 component declare a required inbound property?

Tags: typescript, angular

As subject, I am building one common grid component with Angular2, and id property of grid is required.

```
export class GridComponent {

  @Input() public id: string;

}
```

Do you know how I can declare id property as required property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way but you can enforce it like:

```
export class GridComponent {

  @Input() public id: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.id) {
      throw 'The "id" attribute is required!';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is what I want, direct and simple. I thought we could have defined this rule via features from typescript.

Comment: Typescript doesn't have a way. I don't know TS too well because I'm using Dart but Dart can enforce fields to be set (by adding `final`). This requires that values are initialized in the constructor. If some kind of binding is used like `[id]="generatedId"` then this is not yet available in the constructor but only when `ngOnChanges()` is called the first time, therefore this can't be handled by language features.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should define validation inside `component.html`

Please have a look [Angular Form Guid](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required
  [(ngModel)]="model.name"
   ngControl="name" >
```

Comment: Thanks Tiwari. What I want is not business level thing but from widget level.

Comment: Typescript also have a library https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator.ts for model validation.